# Open external App like Spotify in iOS10 with Ionic suddenly doesn't work

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, url-scheme, ios10

in my Ionic (v1)(Phonegap Build) App I open, with a touch of a button, some Apps like Spotify, Deezer or Napster. Since i updated to iOS10 none of them will open anymore. Debugging with Safari got me no errors at all.

I tried to search the Internet but couldn't find any explanation for this. 
I open these Apps like this:

```
// Open in Android
navigator.app.loadUrl("spotify:album:"+spotifyID, {openExternal : true});
// Open in iOS
$window.open("spotify:album:"+spotifyID);
```

It worked without any Problems up to iOS9 but in iOS10 nothing happens when I touch the Button. Are there any Changes to this i couldn't find?

Thank you for any hint.

EDIT: I tested window.open with normal URLs and they are working. But all my App URL Schemes like Spotify don't since iOS10.

Comment: If you use the full URI scheme (`spotify://album/SpotifyID`) is there any difference?

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: Ahh. Do the schemes work if you enter them directly into Safari?

Comment: yes they work like they should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the normal web url (open.spotify.com) in iOS 10.